# Recursive/Explicit Formula, Geometric/Arithmetic Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Write an explicit formula for the following arithmetic sequence $-4,-1,2,5, \ldots$

Write an recursive formula for the following arithmetic sequence $-4,-1,2,5, \ldots$

Write an explicit formula for the following geometric sequence $\frac12,\frac32,\frac92, \ldots$

Write an recursive formula for the following geometric sequence $\frac12,\frac32,\frac92, \ldots$

Comment: not sure where to begin

Comment: (assuming we start counting the initial term as the zeroth term) The explicit formula for the sequence $0,1,2,3,4,\dots$ is $f(n)=n$.  The recursive formula is $f(0)=0,~f(n+1)=f(n)+1$.  On the other hand, something like $1,3,5,7,\dots$ would have explicit formula $g(n)=2n+1$ and recursive formula $g(0)=1,~g(n+1)=g(n)+2$.  If you start counting the initial term as the first term instead, it works similarly.  For geometric, instead of adding the same amount each time, you instead multiply the same amount each time.

Comment: For each question, ask yourself "*where did we start*" and "*how much are we adding/multiplying each time*"

Comment: can you explain with these problem? i know how to plug in just not with recursive and explicit

Comment: Can you show the slightest effort in showing what you have attempted first?  What do you know about arithmetic sequences?  What do you know about geometric sequences?  What is the initial term of each?  How much did we add/multiply to go from the initial term to the next term?

Comment: explicit: an = a1 + (n-1)d recursive: an = a^n-1 +d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sequences, we have many options on how to notate it.  Take for example the sequence:

$$3,8,13,18,23,28,33,\dots$$

We have the following options (among many others) based on personal preference.

$$\underbrace{3}_{\text{term 0}}, \underbrace{8}_{\text{term 1}}, \underbrace{13}_{\text{term 2}},\dots$$

and

$$\underbrace{3}_{\text{term 1}}, \underbrace{8}_{\text{term 2}}, \underbrace{13}_{\text{term 3}},\dots$$

Which you use is up to you.  So long as you are consistent with your use.  Computer programmers often prefer starting as the initial term is term zero.  Linguists prefer the initial term to be term one.

**From here out, I will use the initial term as term zero.**  You may easily correct what I say to work for the initial term as term one instead.

Now, notating the entries in the sequence, we have more options.  Some people prefer functional notation:

$f(0)=3, f(1)=8, f(2)=13, f(3)=18,\dots$

Other people prefer subscript notation:

$a_0 = 3, a_1=8, a_2=13, a_3=18,\dots$

Again, what you use is up to you.  Just be consistent with how you use it.

---

**Explicit formulae** will give an expression for the $n^{th}$ term which solely depends on $n$ and constants but will not use additional information about the sequence.

In the above example: $3,8,13,18,\dots$ we have $a_n = 5n+3$

Check that it works:  $a_4 = 5\cdot 4 + 3 = 20+3 = 23$ which is correct.

**Recursive formulae** will give an expression for the $n^{th}$ term of the sequence $\underline{\text{where the expression is allowed to use previous entries of the sequence in its formula}}$.  Also necessary for a complete answer would be an initial condition (or initial conditions depending on context).

In the above example: $a_n = a_{n-1}+5$

For example, $a_2+5 = 13+5 = 18 = a_3$ so yes, $a_3=a_2+5$

---

Arithmetic sequences are special in that their recursive formula is of the form $a_n = a_{n-1}+k$ for some real number $k$ which doesn't change from term to term.

Geometric sequences are special in that their recursive formula is of the form $a_n = a_{n-1}\cdot k$ for some real number $k$ which doesn't change from term to term.

Arithmetic sequences will have explicit form: $a_n = kn + a_0$

Geometric sequences will have explicit form: $a_n = k^n\cdot a_0$

(*note: if you consider the initial term as term one, the above would be $a_n = k(n-1)+a_1$ and $a_n = k^{n-1}\cdot a_1$ respectively*)

In each case $k$ here represents the amount added each step or the amount multiplied each step respectively.

Note further that not all sequences will be one of geometric or arithmetic.  There are many strange and complicated sequences found in nature and mathematics.  Finding recursive and explicit formulae can be a big challenge.  There are many which we still haven't found formulae for that we have tried looking for.

Comment: Thanks dude really helped!